# Ошибка в docker-compose File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>, как решить?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

В docker только начал разбираться, может быть кто-нибудь из опытных/знающих людей подскажет куда смотреть, как решить ошибку. Хотел развернуть WordPress, пользовался гайдом с [оф. доков docker](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/), делал всё как там описано.

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 121, in perform_command
  File "compose\cli\command.py", line 38, in project_from_options
  File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 55, in tls_config_from_options
  File "ntpath.py", line 85, in join
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

**docker-compose.yml** точно такой же, как в оф. документации

version: '3.3'

```
services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    dbdata:
```

Comment: Приложите ваш `yml` файл

Comment: Приложил, но он точно такой же, как и в оф. доках

Comment: Какая версия `docker-compose`?

Comment: 1.19.0, build 9e633ef3

Comment: Попробуйте собрать каждый контейнер отдельно через `docker build`

Comment: Затем еще раз `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Через docker biuld, как здесь описано https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-manually-build-docker-containers-for-wordpress/ ?

Comment: `docker-compose build <imagename>`, извиняюсь не правильно написал

Comment: @FCh $ docker-compose build mysql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 121, in perform_command
  File "compose\cli\command.py", line 38, in project_from_options
  File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 55, in tls_config_from_options
  File "ntpath.py", line 85, in join
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
Failed to execute script docker-compose

Comment: Проверьте ваш `compose` файл, может при копировании какие-то непечатные символы вставились

Comment: Нет, абсолютно такой же, как и в доках

Comment: У меня, видимо, что-то с docker-compose. Такая же ошибка: $ docker-compose top
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 121, in perform_command
  File "compose\cli\command.py", line 38, in project_from_options
  File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 55, in tls_config_from_options
  File "ntpath.py", line 85, in join
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
Failed to execute script docker-compose

Comment: Попробуйте переустановить `compose`

Comment: @FCh а как это сделать на windows?)

Comment: Удалить файл, который качается в при [установке](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose). Можно еще сам докер переустановить